# Query regarding overriding in Java

Tags: java

Consider I have a interface like this:

```
public interface Test {
  //Basically life cycle methods
  public void beforeStart(); 
  public void start();
  public void end();
}
```

And there is a abstract class, which provides basic or empty implementations for all of the methods.

```
public abstract class TestAdapter implements Test {
   //Implementations here
}
```

So that clients extending `TestAdapter`, can override one, or all of the life cycle methods. I am mandating each consumer should extend `TestAdapter` class and they can override all or one or none of the lifecycle methods in `TestAdapter`.

But the problem is each consumer of `TestAdapter` creates an instance of a POJO class for which life cycle should be managed ie `beforeStart()` etc.

My question is:

1. There is no problem if client overrides all of the life cycle methods, but if he don't override anyone of the method, I should be able to execute default services for that particular life cycle method and for which I need reference to the user created POJO in `testAdapter` implementation class. How can I proceed to implement this??
2. As you are aware this is somewhat similar to servlet's life cycle. So can anyone guide me? Or Am I complicating my design?

Please let me know if you need more clarifications regarding same.

Edit:
**Note**: If you feel I am trying to re-invent wheel, can you kindly suggest any alternative for above requirements?

Comment: How is the POJO and testAdapter related? Is it a memeber of testAdapter or an adaptation of testAdapter?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj testAdapter contains empty/some default implementations for life cycle of POJO which client provides for by extending testAdapter class.

Comment: If I have to implement a lifecycle kind of mechanism for a POJO, I would firstly have an attribute in my POJO which holds the current LifeCycleState. I would have a common class in your case testAdapter or its extensions to manage the LifeCycle, also the states would be part of an enum, such alll users doesn't mess with it with their own way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think that you should use annotations as you can see in most test frameworks:

```
@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass() {
  // code here
}

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() {
  // code here
}
```

If you really want to stick with inheritance you can do something like this:

```
public abstract class TestAdapter implements Test {

    private AbstractPojo myPojo;

    protected void doBeforeStart(){
        // do something which you always want to happen
        beforeStart();
    } 
    protected void doStart() {
        start();
    }
    protected void doEnd() {
        end();
    }

    // your empty implementations of Test here

    // getter and setter for myPojo
}
```

In this case you can control internally what should happen and let your users override the methods in the interface as they see fit.

Comment: Thank you, but I have some POJO which client will provide it by extending abstract class. So my question is how can I pass this reference to all of above class? or should I first create some sort of object in abstract class and pass a client provided pojo to it? is it possible?

Comment: You can create a get/setPojo method in your abstract class and a field for it there. So in the implementation your user can setPojo(myPojo) and the parent class will see the reference. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I think you're right. So parent class can use it reference and the values provided by client will be visible for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have an argument in the method to control the *POJO* object.
On the other hand, there are a lot of ready frameworks to use instead of creating your own, why invent the wheel again?

Comment: _You can have an argument in the method to control the POJO object_ can you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is of "Creating an object step by step". This is solved by a [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Here is [another example](http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/builder-pattern/) in java for implementing Builder pattern.

Comment: Thank you,I think this somewhat comes closer to my solution, but I will wait for some more answers :)